# Finding duplicate rows but skip the last result?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find duplicate rows in my DB, like this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(emailid) AS NumOccurrences 
FROM   users 
GROUP BY emailid HAVING ( COUNT(emailid) > 1 )
```

This returns the emailid and the number of matches found. Now what I want do is compare the ID column to another table I have and set a column there with the count.

The other table has a column named *duplicates*, which should contain the amount of duplicates from the select. So let's say we have 3 rows with the same *emailid*. The *duplicates* column has a "3" in all 3 rows. What I want is a "2" in the first 2 and nothing or 0 in the last of the 3 matching ID rows.

Is this possible?

**Update:**

I managed to have a temporary table now, which looks like this:

```
mailid | rowcount | AmountOfDups
643921 | 1 | 3
643921 | 2 | 3
643921 | 3 | 3
```

Now, how could I decide that only the first 2 should be updated (by mailid) in the other table? The other table has mailid as well.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal having identified the duplicates?  Remapping any occurrences of the ids and then deleting?

Comment: Its required to highlight the ones that are duplicates in a Report (MS Reporting Services). It should say that 2 of the displayed rows are duplicates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY emailid DESC) AS RN
FROM ...
```

...is a great starting point for such a problem.  Never underestimate the power of ROW_NUMBER()!

Comment: I dont see how this might help in my case, can u point me some more :-)?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Server 2005+ you could try something like (full example)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Email VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Email) SELECT 'a'
INSERT INTO @Table (Email) SELECT 'b'
INSERT INTO @Table (Email) SELECT 'c'
INSERT INTO @Table (Email) SELECT 'a'
INSERT INTO @Table (Email) SELECT 'b'
INSERT INTO @Table (Email) SELECT 'a'

; WITH Duplicates AS (
        SELECT  Email,
                COUNT(ID) TotalDuplicates
        FROM    @Table
        GROUP BY    Email
        HAVING  COUNT(ID) > 1
)
, Counts AS (
        SELECT  t.ID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Email ORDER BY t.ID) EmailID,
                d.TotalDuplicates
        FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
                Duplicates d    ON  t.Email = d.Email
)
SELECT  ID,
        CASE
            WHEN EmailID = TotalDuplicates
                THEN 0
            ELSE TotalDuplicates - 1
        END Dups
FROM    Counts
```